# await doesn't wait for the method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem, the last line (awaiting .Stop) doesn't wait for the method to finish. It just instantly closes the console application and doesn't wait for the method to finish.

Can anyone help with this? I do NOT want to block the thread with .Wait()

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rebootAfterClose = false;

    while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.C && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (input.Key != ConsoleKey.R || input.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control)
        {
            continue;
        }

        rebootAfterClose = true;

        break;
    }

    Task.Run(async delegate { await Server?.Stop(rebootAfterClose); });
}
```

Here is the Stop method.

```
public async Task Stop(bool restart)
{
    Console.Clear();

    Logger.Warn("Server is " + (restart ? "rebooting" : "shutting down") + "....");

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    Dispose();

    if (restart)
    {
        Process.Start(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It fundamentally doesn't sense to use asynchrony here at all.  Just make the whole call stack synchronous, from your `Main` method to your `Stop` method.

Comment: The logic in that `while` loop is really convoluted. You could simplify it as: `while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.C && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.R && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
        {
            rebootAfterClose = true;

            break;
        }
    }`

Comment: This code looks more like a Windows service than a console app; are you expecting the main thread to return back to a service host of some kind?

Answer (score 3):

`await` *does* ensure that the rest of the method isn't running until after the object being awaited has completed.  Your async method is:

```
async delegate { await Server?.Stop(rebootAfterClose); }
```

It won't continue on with the rest of the method (which happens to do nothing at all) until after the `Task` returned by `Stop` finishes.

When you call `Task.Run` what *it* does is schedule the lambda you provide to run in another thread (a background thread, specifically; remember that, it's relevant), and then give you back a `Task`, right away, that tells you when it finishes.  You then throw that `Task` on the floor, never look at it, and finish  your `Main` method.  At this point there are no foreground threads running, so your application ends.

So of course fundamentally *something* needs to be running in a foreground thread if you want your application to not just end.  That means either blocking the main thread or, since you're not actually getting anything out of using asynchrony here, just not using asynchronous operations at all and just using synchronous operations instead.  That's frequently more appropriate for console applications.

Comment: The reason I use async in the first place is so that I can wait (the 5 seconds delay) before closing to warn the players in the game. If I used thread.sleep for this it would do the exact same thing.